# Only The Numbers From $50,000.00 And Higher Receive The Format?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want the numbers to be highlighted in yellow.  I have custom formatting set to *($* #,##0.00*);[Red] $* (#,##0.00);;*(@*)

And only the numbers from $50,000.00 and higher receive the format? Below $50,000.00 are not…

Can somebody help me?

Thank you...

Comment: Check your conditional formatting rules, you could do that with a custom number format but not the one that you gave.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the part of your problem regarding $50,000.00 For me, all numbers less than zero are formatted with a red font. to format with a yellow font, change the color in your format string. If that is not what you want, then clarify your English please

Comment: I misspoke… I don't want to change the color of the font. It's the color of the background that I wish to change.

Comment: I found it… If I just transcated the statement… It seems to work…

Comment: =TRUNC(SUM(S$17:S$38),2)

Answer (score 2):

As [I like Excel very much](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11500501/i-like-excel-very-much) stated you can do it by simply;

- Choose the range of the cells which the rules ll be applied.
- On the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting.
- Point to Highlight Cells Rules
- Greater Than...

[image]

- Enter 49999,5
- Choose Custom Format...

[image]

- And Click on Fill tab.
- Choose color yellow.

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you… I tried what you said… And below was the result…